# ArcMap & Catalog: DB connection to ACCDB file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, arccatalog, ms-access

I have successfully established a database connection using ArcCatalog to an access database. I am using Access 2013 and ArcMap 10.2.2. I used as a database provider Microsoft Jet Engine version 12.0 when creating the connection in Catalog. When trying to import some of the tables into the ArcMap table of contents I get the following error message:

> Warning Could not add the specified data object to the map
>
> General function failure [Export_Table]
>
> The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot read the data in Export_Table
>
> The Minimum required version to read the data it 14.0.0000.0000

Some tables (from the same database) still upload however. This is true for those which were not altered by queries or calculated fields, etc in the database. I'm suspecting this is partially the reason why they won't upload. I tried searching for a version 14.0 but can't seem to find it. Anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: Looks like it's not being distributed anymore, however this seems to be a workaround - changing specified driver name from 12 to 14. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2047dbdb-0003-41a3-abaa-a9cadfb608d5/64-bit-microsoft-ace-oledb-drivers-for-office-2010?forum=sqldataaccess

Comment: Where to change the specified name? I can't even see it in data link properties under "Add OLE DB Connection" in ArcCatalog....